# selecting rows from table which have distinct values for a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

In my thread based messaging system, the table schema is

```
> messages table
id(int auto incr primary key)
body(varchar)
time(datetime)

>message_reference table
id(int auto incr primary key)
message_id(forgain key from message table)
sender
receiver
```

Here, I want to select the first message id which is sent to a new receiver and sender is the user who is logged in.

Doing this with multiple queries and some code is obviously possible but can it be done with a single query for performance issues??

Comment: Huh? Can you provide some example data and expected outcome? What constitutes a "new" receiver? How do you know who is logged in? Are you actually seeing performance problems when you use multiple queries?

Comment: Why do you need two tables? It looks to me like this would be a 1-1 relation so you could put everything in one table.

Comment: @cyberdude: Putting it in one table increase redundancy in my db when a user sends a message to multiple receivers. The entire message needs to be inserted again and again.

Comment: @tom: New receiver means a receiver id which is not yet selected by the query. The user logged in determined by the code and is queried by the code. Possible outcomes are for ex, I have send 3 messages to tom, so it should return only last sent message not the 1st two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

EDIT:

If the id is auto increment, then the id will also increase with time and you can use:

```
SELECT message_reference.message_id, message_reference.receiver, messages.body
FROM message_reference, messages
WHERE message_reference.message_id IN (SELECT  MIN(message_reference.message_id)
                            FROM message_reference
                            GROUP BY message_reference.receiver)
AND message_reference.message_id = messages.id AND message_reference.sender = <sender>
```

Comment: the receiver is not known to us, It should be returned from the query.

Comment: if the message id is an auto inc field, won't the first msg have the lowest id? can that assumption be made?

Comment: No, message_id is not auto increment, Id in the message table is auto incr. In addition, I don't, you can make a query like
SELECT * FROM MESSAGE_REFERENCES WHERE MIN(MESSAGE_ID) AND SENDER=<SENDER>

Comment: yes, so the id in the message table is an auto inc value and is a foreign key in the message references table. If the messages are stored in the db with the timestamp of exactly when they are created, then logically the earliest message would have the least number, right?

Comment: Yeah I think what you are saying is correct, But I don't know how you are gonna determine the receiver to make that query, Can you please write the query you are thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best guess as to what you want, but it would be easier if you gave known inputs, example data, and expected output.

```
SELECT
    MR2.message_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        MR.sender,
        MR.receiver,
        M.MIN(`time`) AS min_time
    FROM
        Message_References MR -- Either use plural names (my personal preference) or singular, but don't mix them
    INNER JOIN Messages M ON
        M.id = MR.message_id
    WHERE
        MR.sender = <sender>
    GROUP BY
        MR.received) SQ
INNER JOIN Message_References MR2 ON
    MR2.sender = SQ.sender AND
    MR2.receiver = SQ.receiver AND
    MR2.`time` = SQ.min_time
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the query you have made? I don't understand whats the MR2 table?

Answer (score 0):

```
select mr.message_id from
  message_reference as mr inner join 
    (select mr1.reciever max(m1.time) as time from messages as m1
       inner join message_reference as mr1 on mr1.message_id = m1.id
       group by mr1.reciever) as last
    on mr.reciever = last.reciever and mr.time = last.time
```

join message reference with "maxtime per reciever" table on reciever and time

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the answer, Just a group by query worked the way I wanted. I used query

```
SELECT SENDER,
RECEIVER,
BODY,
TIME,
MESSAGE_ID
FROM MESSAGE_REF JOIN MESSAGE 
ON  MESSAGE.ID=MESSAGE_REF.MESSAGE_ID
ORDER BY 'TIME' GROUP BY RECEIVER`
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause can come only after the `GROUP BY` clause.
Also, even after exchanging, this doesn't produce the correct results always as the GROUP BY clause will select any of the rows which has that field value at random, and that behavior is indeterminate - so sometimes it will give you the result you want and sometimes it might not

Comment: is so? I didn't knew this behavior of group by clause, It is producing the correct result till now, If what you are saying is correct, I will have to find some other way.

Comment: Yes it is, you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591909/group-by-behavior-when-no-aggregate-functions-are-present-in-the-select-clause