# mysql world database: select country with max population

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the country with the highest population. This is my query:

```
SELECT continent, name, population FROM country HAVING population = MAX(population);
```

Somehow it returns 0 rows.

If i use a nested query it works:

```
SELECT continent, name, population FROM country WHERE population = (SELECT MAX(population) FROM country);
```

So my question is: What is wrong with the first query?

PS: You can download the database here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

---

Alright i think finally i figured out the whole process. Here how it works and why the alternative suggestions/solutions didn't work:

(First of all, as "Dan Bracuk" said in his answer, we have to combine GROUP BY with HAVING and add the aggregate function at the begininng in SELECT statement)

So let's go step by step and try this:

```
SELECT continent, name, population, MAX(population) FROM country;
```

This yields us the first row appended MAX(pop) at the end: 
**"North America", "Aruba", "103000", "1277558000"**

So MAX(population) is just one entry so it restricts the row number to 1 and because i added the continent, name, population columns, mysql just selects the first row from the table.

So if i now write down:

```
SELECT continent, name, population, MAX(population) FROM country HAVING population = MAX(population);
```

I get 0 rows, because 103000 is not equal to 1277558000.

If i use:

```
SELECT continent, name, population, MAX(population) FROM country GROUP BY name;
```

for instance, i get a list of all countries where on each row MAX(population) = population.

So additionally adding "HAVING population = MAX(population)" has no effect since it's already true.

I hope i understood it correctly and could clarify others who wondered why the other solutions didnt work.

Comment: Is this not an example of `HAVING without GROUP BY` problem? If so, then this is an evaluation issue.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you're right. But what do you mean with an evaluation issue?

Comment: I can be wrong on the explanation why your query is failing, but I can shed some light on the "not having `GROUP BY`" issue. `HAVING` is evaluated before `SELECT` and after `GROUP BY`. Imagine your results getting filtered slowly. `FROM` acts first, joining tables if necessary. Next, `WHERE` filters the results from the table. Here's the part that matters to you: `GROUP BY` will turn these rows into groups, then `HAVING` will remove all groups not qualified as per your condition. `SELECT` will now come in and work on the remaining list. This means `HAVING` cannot work on your `SELECT`.

Comment: The above matters because you're doing two things: your referencing on `population` when it cannot be referenced yet. Moreso, you have no `GROUP BY` to "force" `population` to appear. I'm no expert in SQL so the issue with your query might be off the mark. However, the logic of evaluation seems to support this.

Comment: @moller1111 I've edited my answer, and think it answers your question completely.

Comment: +1 for figuring out the logic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select continent, name, sum(population) As sumPop
From country
Group By continent
Order By sumPop Desc
Limit 1;
```

Wow, after lots of trial and error, I see what the issue is now.  First, your initial query seems wrong.  With the database table you are using, you can have multiple regions within the continent.  Therefore, your query will only return (if working correctly) the continent with the single largest region instead of a sum of all regions.  Secondly, you absolutely can use the `max` function within the `having` clause, such as in this example:

```
Select continent, name, max(population) As sumPop
From country
Group By continent
Having sumPop = max(population)
```

(If you do not group by Continent, you will only get one row back.)

However, this is really of no use to you because at this point, the max population is whatever the population is for that row.  Not for every row.  This is because the `having` clause is only looking at the values for that one row (for however many rows you have).  No matter what, you will need a sub query if you want to use the `having` clause in your case (or you can use my initial query), such as below.

```
Select continent, name, sum(population) As sumPop, maxPop
From country
Left Join (Select sum(population) As maxPop
          From country
          Group By continent
          Order By maxPop Desc Limit 1) as TmpTable On (maxPop > 0)
Group By continent
Having sumPop = maxPop
```

`http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab95/26` (This sqlfiddle does not contain all table rows, so the result may be different from your own.)

Comment: He already wrote a query to get the country with the highest population.  He was asking why his first query did not do so.

Comment: ok, i tried this just for test purposes: "SELECT continent, name, population FROM country HAVING MAX(population) > 1;" and it returns me only one row (the first one) althopugh it should return almost all rows. Why?

Comment: With HAVING, it returns 0 rows. With WHERE syntax error. So it doesnt work. But i also wonder why your suggestion does not work.

Comment: By the way you can download the database here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Comment: The first query you suggested was a good query to get the actual answer.

Comment: i don't mean the first query. I ment the second one with HAVING clause. It returns 0 rows. I didn't understand too, why it does not work. With syntax error i meant you have to use HAVING, it does not work with even WHERE.

Comment: i use mysql. That's why i tagged it as mysql.

Comment: and as you added at the end. It also does not give the correct result if i use any type of GROUP BY.

Comment: @James, you are correct about MySQL and sql being different.  The former is database software.  The latter is a programming language.  Both tags are appropriate for the question posed.

Comment: @Dan, can you please answer my question regarding the w3schools example? Why are they giving the example, if it is wrong according to what you wrote in your answer?

Comment: @moller1111: As I see in the link you provided, there is nothing wrong in their approach. Their examples use `GROUP BY` which, "hack-free", is almost always necessary when using `HAVING`.

Comment: @moller1111 I've edited my answer.  I believe if answers your question completely.

Comment: @James: Thank you that you dealed with the problem such a long time. I also tried to solve how it works and finally figured out how it works. i edited my question and appended the answer to the end. Please look at it. But i will accept your answer because of your effort.

Comment: @moller1111 It's no problem.  I just wanted the answer myself because it was confusing.  haha~  I'd say it was totally worth the effort.  Great question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with it.  In fact, in some db engines it would throw an error.

First, the having keyword is used with aggregate results, not fields.  Here is an example.

```
select field1, count(*) records
from sometable
group by field1
having records > 10
```

Note that some databases will not allow you use alias names in the having clause.

Next, you say this:

```
having population = max(population)
```

max(population) hasn't really been defined.  You are not selecting it from anywhere.

Comment: Well, they use it here like mine example. Is it false then? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: @moller1111 In the example in the link, `aggregate_function(column_name)` is defined within the `select` clause.  That's why they can use it within the `having` clause.

Comment: well why dows this not work than? "SELECT continent, name, population, MAX(population) FROM country HAVING population = MAX(population);"

Comment: @moller1111 I'm not sure.  That's what I'm wondering myself.  :/  It's something I'll be checking when I get to work tomorrow though.  lol~

Answer (score 1):

Even if I already posted my answer in the comments area, I feel obliged to point this out. Mind you, this might not even be correct, but for Q&A purposes, I must at the very least attempt to point out what is wrong with the first query.

First point: It's not *entirely* wrong. It just happens to be "non-conformist". There are instances where people have forced similar queries to work, but it's almost always an action that begs a long explanation. Suffice to say, "hack-free", `HAVING` works (almost) only with `GROUP BY`.

Second is the evaluation flow of SQL. I might be off the mark here as well, and since I haven't had any experience with SQL for quite a while, but the order I think should stay the same. `FROM-WHERE-GROUP BY-HAVING-SELECT-ORDER BY` was one of the first things I've learned about it, and it acts like a filter of sorts. Going for a `HAVING MAX(population)` when it hasn't pulled out the population yet is a bit of pain to execute. This is partly where subqueries exist: so you can identify a "target" value that can be referenced before `SELECT` ever comes around.

Let's step through your second line, the one with a subquery: `FROM country` gets all the countries. Then you said to SQL on the `WHERE` part, "Hey, let's set a filter. But the filter needs another query. So let's do that." It returns a value, which is the `MAX(population` of the table. Now, he returns that value to `WHERE` so `WHERE` filters out all rows with a population not equal to the condition. Then it returns the continent, name, and population of the country. Simple enough.

Now, the second one: Again, `FROM country` gets all the countries. You have no `WHERE` so you're working with the base table. You didn't put in a `GROUP BY` either, no grouping happened. But then you threw in a `HAVING`, so SQL stops and asks, "Where's the qualifying groups I should throw out? But even if there are no groups and by some chance this query is slightly valid, where's my *condition*?" So you provided a condition, but this condition rests on one simple fact: **Who** is `MAX(population)` referring to? You haven't picked it out of the list anyway, since `SELECT` still has to happen.

In essence, this is partly the reason why you can't do a `SELECT name FROM country WHERE population = MAX(population)`. As far as the flow goes, it doesn't know the max population because it still needs to be evaluated. It's like asking an apple picker to select the best apple from an orchard when he hasn't seen all the apples yet.

Comment: Yeap, you are right about adding MAX(any_col) into the SELECT portion. By the way i finally figured out the whole process and edited my question by appending the answer at the end. Please see it.

Answer (score 1):

While the `WHERE` clause is applied to the source table, the `HAVING` clause is applied to the aggregated data as a last step before returning the result.

In the case of MySQL this is what happens with your query:

- Since you are using the aggregation function `MAX`, MySQL concludes that the query should be an aggregation
- Since there is no `GROUP BY` clause, the aggregation is over the complete table returning a single line
- You are using the fields `continent`, `name`, and `population` which are not in the `GROUP BY` without an aggregation function, while other SQL databases would throw an error, MySQL actually just returns the values of an indeterminate row
- The `HAVING` clause checks if the returned row has the maximum population

Usually this should return 0 rows, but depending on the setup of the actual table, you may actually get a correct answer as you can see in this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79835/7, but this is misleading and breaks down for the minimum.

If you are using a `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregation function like `MAX`, `COUNT`, or `SUM` your query is an aggregation. In that case any field you are using should usually either be included in the `GROUP BY` or enclosed in an aggregation function. Not doing this can lead to subtle bugs which are hard to track down.

See also: [GROUP BY behavior when no aggregate functions are present in the SELECT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591909/group-by-behavior-when-no-aggregate-functions-are-present-in-the-select-clause)

Answer (score 1):

select population, country
from world
where population = (select max(population) from world)

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause is used in filtering data while aggregating at the same time, if the table already contains each continent with its total population, then you do not need to use the max function in the main query cos there will be no need to aggregate the data. Therefore  the `WHERE` will suffice in this case

Also, where you have `Having population = Max(population)` will return nothing because you did not specify the table from which the  `max(population)` will get the data.

Alternatively, in sqlserver you can use the clause  `Where >= ALL` to pull the continent with the highest population in the entire table

```
select  continent, name
from country
where population >= all ( select population
                            from country
                           )
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find the name of the city with the max and counting city from number of city given in table so you can find it through fire given below query.

```sql
select max(city),
       max(count(city))
from emp
group by city
having city=max(city);
```

```
MAX(city)      |   MAX(COUNT(city))
-------------------- -------------------
udhna          |           4
```