# MySql is randomly retrieving different values using the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, syntax, left-join

This query sometimes randomly gives me null values in some rows and sometimes it doesn't. It all started happening when I changed the inner joins for left joins.

```
CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS surveys_temp AS 
  (SELECT SN.id_rep, 
          Coalesce(( Sum(CASE 
                           WHEN SN.score < 7 THEN -100 
                           WHEN SN.score >= 7 
                                AND score < 9 THEN 0 
                           WHEN SN.score >= 9 THEN 100 
                         end) / Count(score) ), 0) AS NRS, 
          SW.wtr 
   FROM   surveys SN 
          INNER JOIN (SELECT id_rep, 
                             Coalesce(( Sum(CASE 
                                              WHEN score < 7 THEN -100 
                                              WHEN score >= 7 
                                                   AND score < 9 THEN 0 
                                              WHEN score >= 9 THEN 100 
                                            end) / Count(score) ), 0) AS WTR 
                      FROM   surveys 
                      WHERE  survey_type = 'WTR' 
                      GROUP  BY id_rep) SW 
                  ON SW.id_rep = SN.id_rep 
   WHERE  SN.survey_type = 'NRS' 
   GROUP  BY SN.id_rep); 

CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders_temp AS 
  (SELECT id_rep, 
          Sum(Cast(ordernumber AS DECIMAL(2, 0))) AS Orders 
   FROM   orders 
   GROUP  BY id_rep); 

CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chats_temp AS 
  (SELECT id_rep, 
          Time_format(Sec_to_time(Cast(Cast(Sum(response_time * -1)/ Count( 
                                  id_session) AS 
                                  DECIMAL(5, 2 
                                              )) AS CHAR(6 
                                  ))), '%H : %i : %s')AS response_time 
   FROM   chats 
   WHERE  chat_type = 1 
   GROUP  BY id_rep 
   ORDER  BY id_rep); 

SELECT R.rep_name, 
       Count(DISTINCT R.id_session)                AS Chats, 
       O.orders, 
       Concat(Cast((o.orders/Count(DISTINCT r.id_session)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(5, 2 
              )), '%' 
       )                                           AS CONVERSION, 
       Coalesce(Cast(s.nrs AS DECIMAL(5, 2)), '0') AS NRS, 
       Coalesce(Cast(s.wtr AS DECIMAL(5, 2)), '0') AS WTR, 
       C.response_time 
FROM   reps R 
       LEFT JOIN surveys_temp AS S 
              ON S.id_rep = R.id_rep 
       LEFT JOIN orders_temp AS O 
              ON O.id_rep = R.id_rep 
       LEFT JOIN chats_temp AS C 
              ON c.id_rep = R.id_rep 
WHERE  R.rep_country IN( 'D.R', 'U.S' ) 
GROUP  BY R.rep_name 
ORDER  BY R.rep_name;
```

Comment: did you try to order the results and see if its truly different data? or just different showing? `ORDER BY`

Comment: It's truly different data, I've compared plenty of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem here is that you are violating the [Single Value Rule](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-single-value-rule/) in that you are grouping only by `R.Rep_Name` yet selecting other fields without introducing them via an aggregate function, e.g. columns `O.Orders` and `C.response_time` (and the derived columns via `Coalesce` and `Concat`)

Because of this violation, it is likely that not all values of the non-grouped, non-aggregated columns have the same values per `Rep_Name` group, and the result is indeterminate. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591909/group-by-behavior-when-no-aggregate-functions-are-present-in-the-select-clause)

**Edit**(from comments below)

> data looks a little better, but some rep_names are repeating

This appears to confirm the non-aggregated columns were not unique. So:

- either the columns can't be shown in the context of `rep_name` groups,
- or you have more discrete groups than you thought
- or you will need to qualify the non-distinct columns with an aggregate such as `Count(O.Orders), AVG(C.response_time)` etc and then change the column headings as such (e.g. "TotalOrders", "AverageResponseTime" etc)

Comment: I'm sorry StuartLC, but can you explain a little better?, I don't understand.

Comment: I've included a couple of links. Unfortunately, MySql allows this. Other RDBMS systems like Oracle and Sql-Server won't allow you to GROUP if you violate the single value rule.

Comment: Ohh i see what you say now, you mean I should add the columns that are not being used for an aggr function into the group by

Comment: I did what you said, and now data looks a little better, but some rep_names are repeating

Comment: Indeed, so the data in the non-aggregated columns wasn't unique. So here's your dilemmna: either the columns can't be shown in the context of `rep_name` groups, or you have more groups than you thought, or you will need to qualify the non-distinct columns with an aggregate such as `Count(O.Orders)`, `AVG(C.response_time)` etc and then change the column headings as such (e.g. "TotalOrders", "AverageResponseTime" etc)