# MySQL GROUP BY selected column empty

Tags: mysql

I'm having a database with with multiple records where I want to group at. For example:

```
cat_id | p_id | amount | sold | date       | title
---------------------------------------------
1      | 1    | 4      | 3    | 2015-04-21 | title of product 1
1      | 1    | 0      | 5    | 2015-04-03 | 
2      | 1    | 3      | 1    | 2015-04-21 | title of product 2
2      | 1    | 0      | 3    | 2015-04-05 |
```

In this table, there are two unique products, p_id `1` in cat_id `1` and p_id `1` in cat_id `2`. Now I want to get all a list of all product, sum its `amount` and `sold`. The title is only filled in where the amount is > 0.
So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT SUM (amount), SUM(sold) cat_id, p_id, title
FROM table
GROUP BY cat_id, p_id
```

This returns me:

```
cat_id | p_id | amount | sold | title
---------------------------------------------
1      | 1    | 4      | 8    |
2      | 1    | 3      | 4    |
```

So now I'm missing my title.
I tried something link `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT title)`, but that concatenates, and that's not what I'm actually looking for. I just need the title.

How would I fix this.

**NOTE: Updated question**

Comment: Would there ever be a case where the title is different for products of the same cat_id and p_id? If that never happens then why do you even need to group by if you only care about amount > 0?

Comment: I updated my Question, the question was not complete! There is also a column `sold` that needs to be summed. Even if `amount == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding MAX() around title will force it to select the NOT NULL value

```
SELECT SUM (amount), SUM(sold) cat_id, p_id, MAX(title)
FROM table
WHERE amount > 0
GROUP BY cat_id, p_id
```

Comment: `MAX()` is doing the job! Great!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue with the titles here is that if you use `GROUP BY` without an aggregation function, the value returned is indeterminate (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591909/group-by-behavior-when-no-aggregate-functions-are-present-in-the-select-clause)).

So your best bet is to work around this somehow -- an obvious solution would be to fill in the `title` for each row , not just where the amount is > 0 (or even better, normalize your data!).  However, if you can't do that, you can use a separator in `GROUP_CONCAT` that doesn't exist in your titles (e.g., '||||'), and since `GROUP_CONCAT` returns a text field, you can use `REPLACE` to get rid of that:

```
SELECT SUM (amount), SUM(sold) cat_id, p_id, REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT title ORDER BY title DESC SEPARATOR '||||'), '||||', '') AS title
FROM table
GROUP BY cat_id, p_id
```

I made a simplified SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82573/8) that maybe you can play around with to get to do what you want it to.

Comment: I didn't fill each row with the title because it is redundant information and this saves space. Your solution is working fine, but the `MAX()` function is also working fine and a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a MAX() on the title so that it pulls the title that is not blank or null. Seems a little strange though that your table is designed that way...

```
SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(sold) cat_id, p_id, MAX(title) AS `Title`
FROM table
GROUP BY cat_id, p_id
```

Comment: `MAX()` indeed works. I left the titles out of the other records to save space because it is redundant information. The table indeed is designed a little bit strange. That's because it was never designed for doing what I do now. Think I have to consider redesigning the table.

Comment: @Timo002 You should probably consider using a lookup table for titles if you want to save space from storing title multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT SUM (amount), SUM(sold), cat_id, p_id, title
FROM table
GROUP BY cat_id
```

Update SQLFiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5ca3/3

Comment: Your solution does not work when the first record in the table doesn't have the `titel`, but the second row has the `title`.