# MYSQL - Return the most recent record before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

I have read a lot of questions and answers regarding very similar questions as this one and the main problem is that they use `LIMIT` as a solution to returning the most recent record which won't work with this query because I need several results back.

Logic follows as:

- Each record has an `effective_date`, when the records value goes into effect.
- Only pull back records who's `effective_date`'s are today or have passed already
- Of the records I pull back, give me the most recent record based on the '`date_entered`' for that record

So far I have been able to accomplish all but the last bit of logic with this query. I can't use an `ORDER BY` after the `GROUP BY`, because the results have already been grouped so I can't get use the `MAX()` date. I need to do the logic in the `WHERE` statement.

```
SELECT
    aos_products.`name`,
    cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.commission_percentage_c,
    cac_customize_agent_comp.date_entered
FROM
    wn_writing_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON wn_writing_number.id = wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida
LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb = cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c
LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = cac_customize_agent_comp.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb
LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products ON aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1aos_products_ida = aos_products.id
WHERE
    wn_writing_number.id = 'b556d816-f2e6-b78f-c776-576c0542585c'
AND wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.deleted = '0'
AND cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.effective_date_c <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY aos_products.`name`
```

WITHOUT the GROUP BY, it returns:

```
     (varchar)     (varchar)                 (datetime)
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | name    | commission_percentage_c |     date_entered     |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 1   | 15.25                   | 2016-07-06 23:57:28  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 1   | 15.75                   | 2016-07-07 00:03:03  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 1   | 16                      | 2016-07-07 00:31:08  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 2   | 14.75                   | 2016-07-07 15:04:02  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

WITH THE GROUP BY it returns

```
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | name    | commission_percentage_c |     date_entered     |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 2   | 14.75                   | 2016-07-07 15:04:02  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 1   | 15.25                   | 2016-07-06 23:57:28  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

What I am trying to get back is:

```
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | name    | commission_percentage_c |     date_entered     |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 2   | 14.75                   | 2016-07-07 15:04:02  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
    | Val 1   | 16                      | 2016-07-07 00:31:08  |
    +---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

Because I need the most recent VAL 1 record back, something like

```
WHERE the datediff BETWEEN NOW() and date_entered = the smallest amount of time compared with other records
```

Comment: using `max()` for date_entered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
        aos_products.`name` as name,
        cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.commission_percentage_c as commission_percentage_c,
        cac_customize_agent_comp.date_entered as date_entered
    FROM
        wn_writing_number
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON wn_writing_number.id = wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb = cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = cac_customize_agent_comp.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb
    LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products ON aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1aos_products_ida = aos_products.id
    WHERE
        wn_writing_number.id = 'b556d816-f2e6-b78f-c776-576c0542585c'
    AND wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.deleted = '0'
    AND cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.effective_date_c <= CURDATE()
    ORDER BY cac_customize_agent_comp.date_entered DESC) t
GROUP BY t.name
```

The idea of this is to sort the records by `date_entered` **before** using `group by`.  From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627904/3676630), the `groupby` will use the pick the first one in the same order of normal `SELECT`.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! I'll definitely keep this answer bookmarked for future use.

Answer (score 0):

using [max()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) for latest datetime

```
SELECT
aos_products.`name`,
cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.commission_percentage_c,
max(cac_customize_agent_comp.date_entered) as  date_entered     
FROM
    wn_writing_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON     wn_writing_number.id = wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida
LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb = cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c
LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = cac_customize_agent_comp.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb
LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products ON aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1aos_products_ida = aos_products.id
WHERE
    wn_writing_number.id = 'b556d816-f2e6-b78f-c776-576c0542585c'
AND wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.deleted = '0'
AND cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.effective_date_c <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY aos_products.`name`
```

Comment: This returns the most recent date_entered column, but the other 2 columns remain unchanged. In other words, it mismatches the data. I believe this is because the columns are in different tables, but I could be wrong