# MySQL group/order behaves differently in 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | text      | language_id | other_id | dateCreated
 1 | something |           1 |        5 | 2015-01-02
 2 | something |           1 |        5 | 2015-01-01
 3 | something |           2 |        5 | 2015-01-01
 4 | something |           2 |        6 | 2015-01-01
```

and I want to get all latest rows for each language_id that have other_id 5.

my query looks like this

```
SELECT *  (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE other_id = 5 
    ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
) AS r 
GROUP BY r.language_id
```

With MySQL 5.6 I get 2 rows with ID 1 and 3, which is what I want.

With MySQL 5.7.10 I get 2 rows with IDs 2 and 3 and it seems to me that the ORDER BY in the subquery is ignored.

Any ideas what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go with the query below:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN 
(

    SELECT 
     other_id,
     language_id,
     MAX(dateCreated) max_date_created
    FROM tbl
    WHERE other_id = 5 
    GROUP BY language_id
) AS t 
ON tbl.language_id = t.language_id AND tbl.other_id = t.other_id AND 
   tbl.dateCreated = t.max_date_created
```

Using `GROUP BY` without aggregate function will pick row in arbitrary order. You should not rely on what's row is returned by the `GROUP BY`. MySQL doesn't ensure this.

Quoting from this <kbd>[**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591909/group-by-behavior-when-no-aggregate-functions-are-present-in-the-select-clause)</kbd>

> In a nutshell, MySQL allows omitting some columns from the GROUP BY,
>   for performance purposes, however this works only if the omitted
>   columns all have the same value (within a grouping), otherwise, the
>   value returned by the query are indeed indeterminate, as properly
>   guessed by others in this post. To be sure adding an ORDER BY clause
>   would not re-introduce any form of deterministic behavior.
>
> Although not at the core of the issue, this example shows how using *
>   rather than an explicit enumeration of desired columns is often a bad
>   idea.
>
> Excerpt from MySQL 5.0 documentation:
>
> When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same
>   values for the columns that are omitted from the GROUP BY part. The
>   server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are
>   indeterminate unless all values are the same.